# What am I doing wrong with the sorted() function?

Tags: python, list, sorting

My problem is that I do not understand why my sorted() is not working propely on integers higher than hunderd.

Code:

```
new_sheets = [sorted(i) for i in new_sheets]
```

Input:

```
[['64', '65', '0'], ['86', '94', '94', '64'], ['99', '111', '103', '90'], ['36', '48', '47', '100']]
```

Output:

```
[['0', '64', '65'], ['64', '86', '94', '94'], ['103', '111', '90', '99'], ['100', '36', '47', '48']]
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: You are sorting strings, not integers.

Comment: @VasilisG. it's important to stress that these results are not "wrong". These are the expected results when sorting strings.

Comment: @VasilisG. `1 < 9` as much as `'1' < '9'`. that is not the reason why `'100' < '99'`, so i find your "explanation" rather confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because they are not integers, they are **Strings**. String sorting works alphabetically, so anything starting with a `1` will come before anything starting with a `2`, `3`, etc. In order to sort as if the are integers, do:

```
new_sheets = [sorted(i, key=int) for i in new_sheets]
```

which will convert them to integers before sorting them but still return the strings. If you want to return integers, do:

```
new_sheets = [sorted(map(int, i)) for i in new_sheets]
```

Comment: I see what you mean, beginner's mistake I guess.
Thank you for the solution, it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Your inputs appear to be strings not ints. Strings are sorted lexicographically (dictionary order) so ‘111’ comes before ‘90’.

Try

```
sorted(int(x) for x in i)
```